# PostgreSQL update and delete property from JSONB column

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

From [this](http://michael.otacoo.com/postgresql-2/manipulating-jsonb-data-with-key-unique/) article, I tried to update or delete property of a `JSONB` column:

```
CREATE TABLE xxx (id BIGSERIAL, data JSONB);
INSERT INTO xxx(data) VALUES( '{"a":1,"b":2}' );
SELECT * FROM data;
 id |       data       
----+------------------
  1 | {"a": 1, "b": 2}
```

create the update function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION jsonb_merge(JSONB, JSONB) 
RETURNS JSONB AS $$
WITH json_union AS (
    SELECT * FROM JSONB_EACH($1)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM JSONB_EACH($2)
) SELECT JSON_OBJECT_AGG(key, value)::JSONB FROM json_union;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

testing:

```
-- replace
UPDATE xxx SET data = jsonb_merge(data,'{"b":3}') WHERE id = 1;
SELECT * FROM xxx;
 id |       data       
----+------------------
  1 | {"a": 1, "b": 3}

-- append
UPDATE xxx SET data = jsonb_merge(data,'{"c":4}') WHERE id = 1;
SELECT * FROM xxx;
 id |           data       
----+-------------------------
  1 | {"a": 1, "b": 3, "c": 4}
```

The question is:

1. is there any drawback of using `JSONB_EACH` (jsonb_merge) instead of `JSONB_EACH_TEXT` (from the article) in this case?
2. how to modify the `jsonb_merge` so if the second parameter property value is `null` (something like `{"b":null}`) the value would be erased?

.

```
-- remove
UPDATE xxx SET data = jsonb_merge(data,'{"b":null}') WHERE id = 1;
SELECT * FROM xxx;
 id |       data       
----+-----------------
  1 | {"a": 1, "c": 4}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question 1**
There should be no signicant drawbacks. As the `value` is converted back to `jsonb` anyhow I would guess it would be more efficient to keep it that way the whole time.

**Question 2**
Just replace your function with the following (only the part `WHERE key NOT IN ...` added):

```
CREATE FUNCTION jsonb_merge(JSONB, JSONB) 
RETURNS JSONB AS $$
WITH json_union AS (
    SELECT * FROM JSONB_EACH($1)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM JSONB_EACH($2)
) SELECT JSON_OBJECT_AGG(key, value)::JSONB
     FROM json_union
     WHERE key NOT IN (SELECT key FROM json_union WHERE value ='null');
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Comment: I made a new question about my previous comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/95778/