# Clarification on UNION ALL of JSONB_EACH result

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

This function used to merge 2 `JSONB` and delete certain key when the value is null, refer to [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/95758) question.

```
CREATE FUNCTION jsonb_merge(JSONB, JSONB) 
RETURNS JSONB AS $$
WITH json_union AS (
    SELECT * FROM JSONB_EACH($1)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM JSONB_EACH($2)
) SELECT JSON_OBJECT_AGG(key, value)::JSONB
     FROM json_union
     WHERE key NOT IN (SELECT key FROM json_union WHERE value ='null');
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

**First question**, why `value = 'null'` works, but `value IS NULL` is not?

**Second question**, is there any bad reason to use `WHERE value <> 'null'` instead of `WHERE key NOT IN (SELECT key FROM ...)` ?

```
CREATE FUNCTION jsonb_merge(JSONB, JSONB) 
RETURNS JSONB AS $$
WITH json_union AS (
    SELECT * FROM JSONB_EACH($1)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM JSONB_EACH($2)
) SELECT JSON_OBJECT_AGG(key, value)::JSONB
     FROM json_union
     WHERE value <> 'null';
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

**Third question**, why this function also incorrect (always returns `NULL`)? Is it because UNION ALL change all resulting record into `TEXT`?

```
CREATE FUNCTION jsonb_merge(JSONB, JSONB) 
RETURNS JSONB AS $$
WITH json_union AS (
    SELECT * FROM JSONB_EACH($1)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM JSONB_EACH($2)
) SELECT JSON_OBJECT_AGG(key, value)::JSONB
     FROM json_union
     WHERE value <> (NULL::JSONB)
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

-- check function:
SELECT COALESCE(jsonb_merge('{}','{"b":null}'),'{"x":"its empty"}'::JSONB) FROM xxx;
      coalesce      
--------------------
 {"x": "its empty"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question 1**
From PostgreSQL Documentation [Table 8.23 - JSON primitive types and corresponding PostgreSQL types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-json.html#JSON-TYPE-MAPPING-TABLE):

```
JSON primitive type | PostgreSQL type | Notes
null                |(none)           | SQL NULL is a different concept
```

So you must not confuse SQL `NULL` value with with `JSON` null type.

**Question 2**
In your previous question you wanted the JSON value null to act as a kind of DELETE type. If you have both `{"b": 3}` and `{"b": null}` in the `UNION` and you do `value <> 'null'` the `{"b": 3}` will not be deleted. When you do `NOT IN` the pair `b:3` will be left out of the new set too (the null type is found for the key "b" in the subquery).

**Question 3**
Related to question 1: `NULL::JSONB` means a SQL NULL value of the data type JSONB, not a JSON null type.