# Postgres 9.4+: JSONB instead of EAV

Tags: postgresql, database-design, json, eav

I'm figuring out a way to structure a new PostgreSQL database, and I'm curious if I could use a JSONB column instead of the EAV model for storing properties of an entity. This seems like a flexible way to store these kinds of things.

In the EAV case, I would have 3 tables:

```
materials (mat_id, mat_name, mat_descr)
material_properties (prop_id, prop_name, prop_desc)
material_property_values (mat_id, prop_id, val)
```

Each material can have a different set of properties.

Are there any reasons why I shouldn't just add a column `mat_props JSONB` to my `materials` table, and store all properties there as `{"name":"value"}`? This way, querying properties as columns would be as easy as:

```
SELECT mat_name, mat_props->'name' as propval FROM materials
```

instead of joins or subselects.

Also, could I add this column in the `materials` table or would it be much more performant to keep it in a separate table as:

```
material_properties (mat_id, properties JSONB)
```

Comment: I'd suggest just putting together both versions, insert a decent amount of data into both and do some tests.

Comment: What's wrong with using proper relational tables? CREATE TABLE material (mat_id SERIAL (PRIMARY KEY).... melting_point INTEGER, colour VARCHAR(20).... &c...)?

Comment: @Vérace Different materials have different properties that you don't always now upfront. Design should be generic and easily allow to create new properties on the fly. Adding a column each time a new property is added is not really best practice I guess, and you'd end up with a table having 100+ columns.

Comment: Please do as @dezso suggests and answer your own question here. I'm guessing jsonb will win as it has been a much touted feature for this kind of use case. I've seen some benchmarks and it's very fast.

Comment: @Colin'tHart: I'll do some tests, but I was mostly interested to hear if anyone has any reasons not to do it from a design point of view.

Comment: It's been a while, but I've finally gotten to run some [tests](http://coussej.github.io/2016/01/14/Replacing-EAV-with-JSONB-in-PostgreSQL/) for both approaches.

Answer (score 6):

JSONB may be easy to read, but it's complicated and inefficient to write into.

See for example this question: [PostgreSQL update and delete property from JSONB column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/95758/postgresql-update-and-delete-property-from-jsonb-column), on how it looks like. It's an order of magnitude harder than an update/delete with classic EAV tables.

Possibly when you'll have written the parts to append/merge/delete key/value pairs, the elegance or simplicity of that JSON-based design are going to seem much less obvious. As for the performance, I'm betting on it being much worse.

At the storage level, any write into one property in a JSON structure will require a rewrite of the entire column (and in fact of the containing row), with the same cost as if all properties changed. 
This is not optimal in terms of I/O size and  pressure on vacuum.

This problem is mentioned on S.O in another question with some more links and references:

[How to perform update operations on columns of type JSONB in Postgres 9.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26703476)

There's ongoing work to ease JSONB updates for the programmer. [jsonbx](http://pgxn.org/dist/jsonbx/) provides functions and operators that can help with 9.4; presumably these will be integrated into PostgreSQL core in future versions. But the large I/O cost of a small update inside a large JSON object will remain.

`jsonbx` was demonstrated in a recent PG conference (youtube links):

[Update and Delete operations for jsonb (part 1 of 2)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4SaBDf3EliU)
[Update and Delete operations for jsonb (part 2 of 2)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ln2WUAH0-LA)

Comment: Reading between the lines, if the data is mostly just inserted and then queried with very few updates, it could still be a good solution?

Comment: @Colin'tHart: yes if we're refering to INSERT at the SQL level, as creating new rows. But inserting a new key into a JSON column means an UPDATE of that column at the SQL level.